# Display Image from URL in Dataspell

Tags: html, dataframe, image, url

I would like to know how can I display images in a column by using their URL? I have tried on Google Colab and it has worked, but when I try on my jupyter notebook (data spell), it doesn't display the images.

```
from IPython.core.display import HTML
#%%
## Converting links to html tags
def path_to_image_html(path):
    return '<img src="'+ path + '" width="60" >'
#%%
## Rendering the dataframe as HTML table
df.to_html(escape=False, formatters=dict(image=path_to_image_html))

## Rendering the images in the dataframe using the HTML method.
HTML(df.to_html(escape=False,formatters=dict(image=path_to_image_html)))

and it returned me the this instead of the image ;<img src="url of the image" width="60">
```